# How can i get the data into the relationship table

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, backend

Here is the Code and after using runserver its working fine but i want do add code so that my relationship table will get the data also.

```
from django.db import models
from smar_group_app.models import smar_group


# Create your models here.
class report(models.Model):

    SmarGroup = models.ManyToManyField(smar_group)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    reportname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    pagecategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    pagesubcategory = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    district = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

serializers.py

from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import report


class reportserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = report
            fields = '__all__'   

views.py 

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from .serializers import reportserializer
from .models import report
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView


# Create your views here.
class report_list(ListAPIView):

    queryset = report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = reportserializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filterset_fields = ['state','region','created_at']

@api_view(['GET'])
def report_details(request, pk):

    reports = report.objects.get(id = pk)
    serializer = reportserializer(reports, many = False)
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def report_create(request):
    serializer = reportserializer(data = request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['PATCH'])
def report_update(request, pk):

    reports = report.objects.get(id = pk)
    serializer = reportserializer(reports ,data = request.data, partial = True)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data)    


@api_view(['Delete'])
def report_delete(request, pk):

    reports = report.objects.get(id = pk)
    reports.delete()
    return Response("Deletion Completed")
```

SMAR Group Model

```
from django.db import models
from pages_app.models import PageInfoModel

# Create your models here.
class smar_group(models.Model):

    page_smar_group = models.ManyToManyField(PageInfoModel)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    geo_level = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    geo = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    page_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    page_sub_category = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    political_party = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
```

Smar Serializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import smar_group

class smar_group_serializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = smar_group
        fields = '__all__'
```

here I want to get the data into relational table. what should i do for that?
I am creating the models and the Crud oprations and everything is working good just want a help to app data into relational table

Comment: You mean the relationship with `SmarGroup` model?

Comment: Yes i want that

Comment: Okay, then can you add the content of the `SmarGroup` model and it's serializer into your post here?

Comment: Done now please tell me how to do it ?

Comment: When we see the data in the smar group relational table how can we set the variable to be seen

Comment: please check another problem i have asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73412251/how-to-get-the-set-of-variable-to-been-seen-when-checking-the-list

Answer (score 0):

You could just add the `SmartGroup` field to get the related data.

```
class reportserializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    SmartGroup = smar_group_serializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = report
        fields = '__all__'
```